# Sorting an unsorted array using only max(i,j) and a reverse(j) function

Tags: python, algorithm

I have just recently gotten myself into basic algorithms (trying to mostly experiment with python) and I was wondering whether it would be possible to sort an array from the lowest to highest value using only max(i,j) and a reverse(i) function. I have already written the reverse function by myself and I am stuck on how I could possibly incorporate it into solving the problem.
Here's what I have come up with so far:

```
list = [4,2,5,3,1]

def reverse(array, index):
    n = array
    first = 0
    while first < index:
        if(index <= 0 or index > len(array)):
            return n
        else:
            holder = n[first]
            n[first] = n[index]
            n[index] = holder
            first += 1
            index -= 1
    return n

print(reverse(list, 3))
```

Any tips or tricks would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance.
EDITED: Changed to a function that actually works

Comment: There are lots of ways to do it. The main thing is you need to figure out how to combine multiple calls to `reverse` in order to move an element from one place to another while leaving some section of the list unchanged.

Comment: Note that `n = array` doesn't make a copy, so you're not only returning a reversed array but also reversing the original.